# Record of empty memory locations

Tags: memory, data-structures, compiler-construction, location, memory-address

like a linked list I know that free space from different memory location is given .... But how do a compiler know a free space is available in a memory?

How do memory keeps record of free pool stuff is there any data structure used to store the free memory addresses like linked list

Comment: The compiler doesn't keep track of free memory. All it does is compile the program. When the program is executed, the compiler is no longer involved. Memory is allocated by a memory allocation library (see `malloc` in the standard C library, but there are other possibilities). The only involvement the compiler has with memory allocation is acquiring and releasing the memory it itself needs in order to compile the program, and for that it uses a memory allocation library, just like any other program. (Although there may be optimisations in place to allow recycling of small allocations.)

Comment: then how do malloc function knows? Does addresses of free memory is stored in a linked list or any data structure

Comment: It depends on the malloc implementation, and it might not be the same for all malloc blocks. But I think that without exception, the information is stored in some kind of data structure.